# How to update linked document in mongoose from parent?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `User` model with a `profile` field pointing to profile model, like

```
UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
      unique: false,
  },
  profile:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile'}});
```

Now it is saving fine, but I want to update the User and Profile at the same time by sending an object like:

```
{
name : 'some name',
profile.location : 'some location'
}
```

my simple update code:

```
User.update({_id:userId},req.body,{},function(){
      res.status(204).end();
    });
```

It seems to only update the `User`'s name, but not the linked `Profile` document's properties. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) (`ref` used in `profile`) is introduced into `Mongoose`,

> Because there are no `joins` in MongoDB but sometimes we still want references to documents in other collections. Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s).

So it is not related to `update` operation for the reference document. Here are one sample codes to meet your requirement.

```
User.update({_id: userId}, 
            {name: req.body.name}, function(err, u) {
            if (err)
               console.log(err);
            else {
               Profile.update({_id: u.profile}, 
                              {location: req.body.profile.locatio}, 
                              function(err) {
                                  // error handling
              })
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [DaftMonk's Angular Fullstack Generator](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack), then just do this :

1. Install **lodash** `npm install lodash`
2. Include lodash in your JS file like this : `var _ = require("lodash");`
3. Finally do this :

   `var newUser = {};
   newUser.name = "Some Name";
   User.findById(userId, function(err, user){
       if(err) console.log(err);
       var updated = _.merge(user, newUser);
       updated.save(function (err) {
         if (err) console.log(err);
         Profile.findById(user.profile._id, function(err, profile){
            profile.location = "some location";
            profile.save(function(err){
               if(err) console.log(err);
               console.log("Updated User and Profile");
           });
         });
       });
   });`

Hope this helps.